# "Out of Office" message works only as a Client rule

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2010

I am attempting to set an 'Out of Office' message on Outlook 2010 for a colleague (running 64-bit Windows 7).  Once the rule is complete, I get a message which says that the rule is a Client rule and will only work when Outlook is running.  I'm using Exchange 2007.  How can I set it up so that the 'Out of Office' message will work regardless of whether Outlook is running or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To ensure full support of Outlook 2010, make sure to upgrade your Exchange server 2007 to [Service Pack 3](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24111).
2. Outlook 2007/2010 relies on the autodiscover feature when handling Out of Office replies. Make sure you have autodiscovery set up and running correct: [Test-OutlookWebServices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124509(EXCHG.80).aspx) and https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/ are your best friends when troubleshooting this